# Android format an international phone number string with its country code included

Tags: java, android, formatting, phonenumberutils

Let's say I have this `String`:

```java
String phoneNumber = "+15611234567"
```

Using `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phoneNumber);` works here and formats it into `+1-561-123-4567`

**However**, when I have a non-US phone number *with its country code included*, such as

```java
String phoneNumber = "+96170123456" //Lebanese phone number
```

It doesn't work, it just returns it as-is instead of it being formatted.

**Returns:** `+96170123456`

**Expected:** `+961 81-932-452` or any kind of different formatting (e.g `+961 70 123 456`)

In case you need it, here's the code that's not working:

```java
public void setPhone(final String phone){
    TextView phoneTV = view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone);
    phoneTV.setText(formattedNumber);
}
```

The phone number's country code isn't consistent, it could be from any country.

Answer (score 1):

formatNumber (String phoneNo) This method was deprecated in API level 21.

So for API level 21 or above use :

formatNumber(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)